# How to sort 3 dimensional point?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, 3d, point

Suppose you have some points in 3D. You would like to sort it either increasing or decreasing order. You don't consider CW/CCW on sorting. How do you sort?

Comment: Increasing or decreasing order of what? You have to get the concept clear first, something increases or decreases if it is measurable, what is your measure here?

Comment: You would first of all need to define your ordering. Any ordering needs to have a unique way of defining `a>b` that obeys various rules (such as `a>b` and `b>c` means `a>c`). There is no standard way of ordering these things that I know of so you need to define your own (eg sort by x, then by y then by z).

Comment: The fact you are trying to sort three dimensional data probably is the root of your problem. Perhaps with a bit more context of why you are trying to do this we might be able to help more.

Comment: What does CW/CCW mean?

Comment: The answer is "however you want". There are literally infinitely many ways to sort it.

Comment: Really need more details in your question, chap.

Comment: Dukeling: CW/CCW will probably mean clockwise and clounterclockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of sorting 3D points would be to compare their magnitudes - their distance from the origin point (0, 0, 0) - which may be computed using a 3D analogue of Pythagora's Theorem:

[M = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1392933041/eqn.png](http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1392933041/eqn.png)

You'll then have a list of floats/doubles that may be sorted using any conventional sorting algorithm.

That's just the most common method, though. There exist infinitely many ways of comparing 3D points, some of which are more sensible than others. For example, which is the "bigger" point, (1, 0, 0) or (-10, -50, 5)? Comparing the X or Y coordinate would suggest the former being larger, while comparing the Z coordinate or magnitude suggests the latter being larger. None of these answers are completely right or wrong; it really depends on what you need your application to do.

Comment: I don't think that is the only sensible method. It really depends on what you are doing. It is also not sufficiently unique. How do you order `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0)`?

Comment: Distance comparison does not even define a strict order. You won't be able to get a predictable sort with that.

Comment: I suppose you'd also require the use of a stable sorting algorithm to accommodate for such a data set. But that isn't really the point I'm trying to get at; it doesn't make sense to compare the 3D points themselves, so we convert them into something that does make sense to compare - the magnitude. This is the approach used for complex numbers, which can't use notions such as "greater than" directly, but may be compared to some extent by computing their absolute values.

Comment: Of course, if the magnitude isn't useful in the OP's specific application, then it doesn't make sense to use it. But I can't think of anything else that would be at all useful to compare.

Comment: To the downvoters; I assume this was because of the assertion that comparing magnitudes is the only good way to compare 3D points. In retrospect, this was worded rather poorly. I have edited my answer accordingly, and added a note that the true answer depends on what the OP's application requires.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'd personally argue that comparing magnitudes isn't a good way to compare 3d points and I'd imagine the downvoter may well think that. You are bang on though that what is right depends on what the user wants.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. I come from a mathematical background, where I'm used to comparing complex numbers using their magnitude (and having no other good way to do so). I assumed that doing the same in 3D space would be sensible enough, but I guess not :)

Comment: Tetrinity: I support your first comment. My question is how do I calculate magnitude of 3D point? What is magnitude of say point (1,3,5)?

Comment: I've added the formula to calculate it into my answer, since it'd look a little messy in a comment. The magnitude of (1, 3, 5) would be sqrt(35).